# Generic class on two types

Tags: java, generics

I want to create a Java class with two generic types.

```
public class BinaryContractInfo<T, U>
```

The thing is that I would like `U` to be either the same type of `T` or `T[]`.

Basically I would like to know if `T extends T[]` or vice versa. Then I could do something like

```
public class BinaryContractInfo<T, U extends T[]>
```

Is that possible? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Why the desire to do this. Sorry but it doesn't make logical sense to me. Can you give us more information about the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Well I will have to compare the two types.

Comment: Could you simply use one generic type and have method overloads, one accepting the type as a parameter and the other accepting an array of the type?  The code inside the two methods will be different and so I see no advantage towards doing what you initially are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot specify a type as being either `T` or `T[]` Instead you can use varargs

```
public void method(T... ts);
```

which can be called either

```
method(t);
method(t1, t2, t3);
T[] ts = 
method(ts);
```

For return types you can specify

```
public T[] method();
```

if the caller assumes there is only one return value

```
T t = method()[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

No, AFAIK, you can't do that, not to mention that arrays and generics don't play well together. The simplest thing would be to wrap your array in a collection type (`List` or a *very* thin wrapper over an array), if you are allowed to do it that is.

Also, why not just use `T[]` directly in your code instead of having a separate type parameter for it? If you can't, then do explain why you can't.

Comment: Because it can also be `T` and not `T[]`.

Comment: So create a new type which abstracts over the differentiation between `T` and `T[]` and accepts varargs of type `T`? Also, can you update your question with client code i.e. a sample snippet which shows how you would be using your binary contract?